# Monodevelop source compilation errors

Tags: compilation, monodevelop

I am trying to download Monodevelop and compile the source code. Following are the errors which I get

```
{
/home/shankar/Development/Monodevelop/main/Main.sln: error : Could not find the project file '/home/shankar/Development/Monodevelop/main/external/Newtonsoft.Json/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Newtonsoft.Json.csproj'
/home/shankar/Development/Monodevelop/main/Main.sln: error : Could not find the project file '/home/shankar/Development/Monodevelop/main/external/ikvm/reflect/IKVM.Reflection.csproj'
/home/shankar/Development/Monodevelop/main/Main.sln: error : Could not find the project file '/home/shankar/Development/Monodevelop/main/external/xwt/Xwt/Xwt.csproj'
/home/shankar/Development/Monodevelop/main/Main.sln: error : Could not find the project file '/home/shankar/Development/Monodevelop/main/external/xwt/Xwt.Gtk/Xwt.Gtk.csproj'
}
```

I see that all the external dependencies are not found. I used "git clone" to clone the project. Is there a specific git option to download the external dependencies or should I download each project individually to compile?

Thanks for your help

Shankar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

MonoDevelop uses several submodules, you need to also download and check them out.

Comment: great thanks. I just ran two commands
<code>{ git submodule init & 
git submodule update
} </code>
and then did a make, everthing worked like charm.